# Running app with `eb local run` works, but cant actually connect to app

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got a very straightforward Flask application running in a single docker container.  When I run the app using `eb local run` it "works" in that the docker image is built, and I eventually see the log output from flask letting me know it's ready for requests.  But when I actually attempt to query the running application, the requests fail immediately with errors saying 'the site cant be reached'.  It seems like the app is running in the container, but somehow the ports aren't exposed correctly? Also, when I run it using `docker run ...` it works completely and I'm able to query the application.

Command I'm using:
`eb local run --port 5000 --envvars APP_ENV=LOCAL`

My Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": 5000,
      "HostPort": 5000
    }
  ]
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "application.py" ]
```

My .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml:

```
branch-defaults:
  python3:
    environment: fs-service-prod
environment-defaults:
  fs-service-prod:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: followspot-service
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Docker running on
    64bit Amazon Linux/2.12.11
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

Output of `eb local status`:

```
Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.12.11 running Docker 18.06.1-ce
Container name: 6739a687fa2d18f1c683926f024c88bed9f5c6c7
Container ip: 127.0.0.1
Container running: True
Exposed host port(s): 5000
Full local URL(s): 127.0.0.1:5000
```

Thanks so much for any help you can give me and let me know if there's a good way to go about getting more helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  Turns out this was an issue with how I was starting my Flask app.  Because flask by default runs on 127.0.0.1 and Docker by default runs tries to connect to 0.0.0.0, I needed to change how the app is started in my Dockerfile.

Instead of:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "application.py" ]
```

I had to change it to:

```
ENV FLASK_APP application.py
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Then everything worked as expected.